# EXCEL VBA code to export to text file only works if breakpoint set

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code to export data from a spreadsheet to a comma delimeted file.  If I have a breakpoint set anywhere in the code, the data is exported to the file as expected.  If I do not have a breakpoint, the file is created without any data.  Thinking this was a timing issue, I experimented with a wait cycle within the code, but this did not solve the issue. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub WriteDataToFile()  
Dim i As Long
Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim strFile As String
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
Dim FSOFile As TextStream
Dim strData As String
Dim s As String

strFile = "C:\Temp\DSGELIG.txt"
'  Delete the file if it already exists
DeleteFile (strFile)

'  Determine the last row
iLastRow = 50
For i = 2 To 65000
    strData = Range("B" + CStr(i))
    If Len(strData) < 1 Then
        iLastRow = i - 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next i


'  Create the file system object
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set FSOFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForWriting, True)




For i = 2 To iLastRow
    strData = ""
    With Worksheets(1)
        'Debug.Print Range("B" + CStr(i))
        strData = """"
        '  Patient Name
        strData = strData + Range("B" + CStr(i))
        strData = strData + """" + "," + """"
        '  SSN / Policy #
        strData = strData + Range("C" + CStr(i))
        strData = strData + """" + "," + """"
        '  Birthdate
        strData = strData + CStr(Range("D" + CStr(i)))
        strData = strData + """" + "," + """"
        '  Admit Date
        strData = strData + CStr(Range("E" + CStr(i)))
        strData = strData + """" + "," + """"
        '  Admit Date - 2
        strData = strData + CStr(Range("F" + CStr(i)))
        strData = strData + """" + "," + """"
        '  Account Number
        strData = strData + CStr(Range("G" + CStr(i)))
        strData = strData + """" + "," + """"
        '  Insurance Code
        strData = strData + Range("H" + CStr(i))
        strData = strData + """" + "," + """"
        '  Financial Class
        strData = strData + Range("I" + CStr(i))
        strData = strData + """" + "," + """"
        '  Location
        strData = strData + Range("J" + CStr(i))
        strData = strData + """"

        '  Write the record to the file
        FSOFile.WriteLine (strData)
    End With


Next i

FSOFile.Close

End Sub
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE - its been a while since I have done any VBA.

Answer (score 3):

Updated with how I might do this from scratch:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim arrData(9) As String
    Dim strFile As String, strData As String
    Dim iLastRow As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

    strFile = "C:\Temp\DSGELIG.txt"
    Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(strFile, True)
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    iLastRow = WS.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    With WS
        For i = 2 To iLastRow
            For j = 2 To 10
                arrData(j - 2) = """" & CStr(.Cells(i, j)) & """"
            Next j

            strData = Join(arrData, ",")
            ts.WriteLine Left(strData, Len(strData) - 1)
        Next i
    End With

    ts.Close

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

There's no need for your code that deletes the file because you can simply set `overwrite` to `true` in `CreateTextFile()`.

I have tested this and am not running into any issues with the file getting written. I even tried to create a set of data that might be comparable to yours based off of your original export and it works just fine.

Comment: `With Worksheets(1)` has not effect since you dont prefix .Range with a dot !

Comment: @iDevlop This is true. There's several things that you should be improved on his original code so I'll try to edit my post and include a couple necessary/suggested changes.

Comment: The `With ...` would be more efficient if placed OUTSIDE the `For i...`

Comment: @iDevlop Yeah =P, there's a lot of things that could be done more efficiently here. I'll try to include them all...

Comment: I have made the changes suggested- thankyou for pointing out that I can just overwrite  the file, however, I still have the same issue.  If I have a breakpooint in the code, data gets written to the file.  If I dod not have a breakpoint, I get a 0 byte file without any data.  Very Strange Behavior.

Comment: I am starting to understand why my original try of using worksheet.cells did not work.  I have attempted to write this code as an Excel Add In so it can be distributed to other users.  The Add in however, does not see the worksheet in the excel file which has a tab name of DATA but rather just SHeet 1 on the original excel file.  I am not sure why this is the case?  Any ideas? THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

I reworked a bit Kittoes code, as this:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim strFile As String, strData As String
    Dim iLastRow As Integer, i As Long, c As Long

    strFile = "C:\Temp\DSGELIG.txt"

    '  Determine the last row
    iLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    '  Create the file system object
    Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(strFile, True)
    With Worksheets(1)
        For i = 2 To iLastRow
            strData = ""
            For c = 2 To 10
                strData = "'" & strData & .Cells(i, c) & "',"
            Next c

            '  Write the record to the file without the last comma
            ts.WriteLine Left(strData, Len(strData) - 1)
        Next i
    End With

    ts.Close

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

I must say that I have never used FSO.CreateFile and the rest. I usually use the old `Print #1` syntax. I generally try to avoid any additional reference if I can.